# Creating new event in iOS5 Calendar by opening an iCalendar (.ics) file

Tags: ios, ipad, calendar

According to [Apple's iOS 4.2 release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-4_2/_index.html):

> Calendar can now import .ics files directly as a way to add events. If
>   your app has access to .ics files, you should test importing them
>   using the UIDocumentInteractionController API.

I'm opening a sample `.ics` file using `UIDocumentInteractionController` and the iOS Calendar app appears, but it hasn't created a new appointment -- it just shows whatever it was showing when the Calendar app was last used. Has anyone had any luck with creating new events this way?

My code for the `UIDocumentInteractionController` usage is:

```
- (void)openDocumentIn {    
    NSString * filePath = 
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
     pathForResource:@"testevent" ofType:@"ics"];    

    self.documentController = 
        [UIDocumentInteractionController 
         interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];

    self.documentController.delegate = self;

    [self.documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero
                                           inView:self.view 
                                         animated:YES];
}
```

And my sample `.ics` file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:1.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20120411T090000
DTEND:20120411T100000
SUMMARY:Crazy party
LOCATION:Windsor Bouncy Castle
DESCRIPTION:Lots of good stuff will happen.
PRIORITY:3
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I'm running iOS 5.1 on an original iPad.

**Update**

I've tried pre-creating an event in my Calendar that matches the time/data of the `.ical` event, to see if in this case the Calendar app would at least show the already existing  event that matches, but again no luck - the calendar app just opens showing whatever was showing last time.

Comment: Hmmm, I followed your code almost exactly and was able to get the calendar app to pop up and ask me if I wanted to add the events in my ical file. It didn't navigate the calendar to the new entries when I was finished, however. I'll post back here if I figure that out.

Comment: Ah, thanks Jeff, interesting to see you have different behaviour!

Comment: Check if your cloud settings(iPad) are enabled for calendar

Comment: Does this technique work for you in iOS 7? I test it out and gives me 3 options (DropBox, Google Drive and Box) but none is the Calendar app.

Comment: @JeffSchmitz For me the button "Add to calendar" does not appear in the preview. Does it for you?